# How to extract Title and description of a url using php

Tags: php, url, title, extract

I trying to  extract title, description and keywords of url. The code below is working fine for a single line  description but not for multiple line description.  Could anyone help regarding this. It would be would If I could know how to extract  image also like social bookmarking site does.

```
<?php

  $url = "http://www.apnatimepass.com";

  $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
  $content = "";
  while(!feof($fp)) {
        $buffer = trim(fgets($fp, 4096));
        $content .= $buffer;


    }


  $start = '<title>';
  $end = '</title>';
  preg_match('!<title>(.*?)</title>!i', $content, $match);
  $title = $match[1];
  $metatagarray = get_meta_tags($url);
  $keywords = $metatagarray["keywords"];
  $description = $metatagarray["description"];
  echo " <div><strong>URL: </strong >$url</div> \n";
  echo  "<div><strong>Title:</strong>$title</div>\n";
  echo " <div><strong>Description: </strong >$description</div>\n";
  echo " <div><strong>Keywords: </strong >$keywords</div>\n";

  ?>
```

Comment: Maybe this works: `!<title>(.*?)</title>!im`, with multiline modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://urlhere.com');
$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$title = $title[0];
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$description = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[name@="description"]/@content');
$keywords = $xpath->query('/html/head/meta[name@="keywords"]/@content');
```